# Why don't I have center alignment on mobile website?

Tags: html, css, mobile

When I open the page on the phone it is not centered instead all goes to the left side, whereas when I open it on the computer everything looks nice.

I tried to add and remove codes to the page for example add min-width/max-width,change valutes - %/px .

HTML--------------

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Farbawlesie </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styl.css">
        <meta http-equiv="Imagetoolbar" content="no" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="naszywka3.gif">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="farbawlesie.pl/favicon.ico">
        <meta charset= "UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body oncontextmenu="return false" background="las.jpg">
        <div id="page-wrap">
            <div id="baner">
                <img src="banern.png"  height="250">
            </div>
            <hr color="white">
            <br><br><br>
            <center>
                <div id="menu">
                 <ol>
                    <li><font color="yellow">⇒</font><a href="index.html"> Start</a></li>
                    <li><font color="yellow">⇒</font><a href="my.html"> O nas</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="druzyna.html">Drużyna</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="zasady.html">Zasady</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><font color="yellow">⇒</font><a href="Terminarz.html"> Terminarz</a></li>
                    <li><font color="yellow">⇒</font><a href="Forum.html"> Forum</a></li>
                    <li><font color="yellow">⇒</font><a href="Galeria.html"> Galeria</a></li>
                    <li><font color="yellow">⇒</font><a href="Kontakt.html"> Kontakt</a></li>
                  </ol>
                  </div>
            </center> 
            <br><br><br><br>
            <hr color="white">
            <br><br><br><br>
            <font size="5" color="white" family="Times">
            Witaj na naszej stronie ! ☺
            <br>
            Masz pytanie ? Skontaktuj się z nami ! Więcej w zakładce "Kontakt".
            <br><br>
            <center>     
                <div id="srodek_naglowek">
                    <img src="dr.jpg" width="850px"   height="420px"/>
                    <img src="baner.png" width="850px"  height="420px" />
                    <img src="farba.jpg" width="850px"   height="420px"/>
                    <img src="far6.jpg"width="850px"  height="420px"/>
                    <img src="3.png" width="850px"   height="420px"/> 
                    <img src="swt.jpg" width="850px"  height="420px"/>
                </div>
                <center>
                    <br><br><br><br>
                    <hr color="white">
                    <br><br> 
                    <center>
                        <font color="red"><h2>Naszywki członków drużyny</h2></font>
                        <img src="naszywka3.gif">
                        <font size="3" color="white">Otrzymuje każdy członek</font>
                        <br><br><br>
                        <img src="naszywka2.gif">
                        <font size="3" color="white">Otrzymuje osoba która brała 3 razy udział w nocnym strzelaniu</font>
                        <br><br><br>
                        <img src="naszywka1.gif">
                        <font size="3" color="white">Otrzymuje osoba która ma 5 letni staż w stowarzyszeniu</font> 
                        <br><br><br>
                        <hr color="white">
                        <div id="stopka">
                            Copyright © Wszelkie prawa zastrzeżone
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </body>
            </html>
```

CSS-----------------

```
head {
    text-align: center;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
#srodek_naglowek {
    text-align: center;
}
#baner {
    text-align: center;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
} 
#page-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#menu {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Arial;
}
ol {
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: white;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    text-align: center; 
}
ol > li {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}
ol > li > a: hover {
    color: grey;
}
ol > li: hover {
}
#stopka {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
}
ol  {
}
ol > li > ul > li {
}
ol > li > ul > li: hover {
}
ol > li > ul > li: hover a {
    color: grey;
}
ol > li > ul {
    display: none;
}
ol > li: hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
ol > li > ul {
    display: none;
}
ol > li: hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

WEBSITE:
http://www.farbawlesie.pl

Comment: Firstly, I believe you will also benefit from a [HTML Tutorial by W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/) or the [HTML Tag Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp). Secondly, css styling (or any styling on the `<head>` tag will not be applied. Thirdly, the second, third and fourth `<center>` tags in your html do not contain a closing tag: `</center>`.

Comment: [`<center>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) tags are obsolete and should not be used anymore.

Comment: It can be done, but not with `text-align:center;`. If you want it to scale you can apply the css rules directly to the image tag (not the container): `width:100%; max-width: 1300px;` You will need to remove the `height` and `width` attributes from the image tag to let CSS take over styling and scale without changing the aspect

Answer (score 0):

Your header image has a hard-coded width of `1300px`. In smaller screen sizes, there is no room to fit the image, so you're seeing the overflow. Adding the following `CSS` is one way to fix this:

```css
#baner img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main culprit would be the hard-coded dimensions on the images. If you set width and/or height on the image, the browser will not recalculate its size and stretch some of the divs just to fit them in.

The quickest fix would be to remove the height from this image by changing this:

```
<img src="banern.png"  height="250">
```

to this:

```
<img src="banern.png">
```

and then allowing this image to take 100% width:

```
#baner img {
    width: 100%
}
```

This however won't center align your other row of images.
To help the situation, you could update your body properties with overflow-x:hidden, to remove the scroll in the bottom.